Formal justification for symmetry in a probability question

A frog sitting at the point $(1, 2)$ begins a sequence of jumps, where
each jump is parallel to one of the coordinate axes and has length
$1$, and the direction of each jump (up, down, right, or left) is
chosen independently at random. The sequence ends when the frog
reaches a side of the square with vertices $(0,0), (0,4), (4,4),$ and
$(4,0)$. What is the probability that the sequence of jumps ends on a
vertical side of the square? (AMC 12A 2020/11)

I understand the solution for this (Say solution 2 at the link), based on the symmetry of the possible jumps, leading to:
$$1\cdot \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{5}{8}$$
While the symmetry is "obvious" in the sense that the probabilities are interchanged, how would I justify this symmetry in a subjective/proof-based setting. I could do it brute-force by listing out all the possibilities, but that is not very elegant.
Also, a proof of the symmetry that extends to the diagonal of a $n\times n$ square would be really great.

Establish a bijection between winning paths.  If you permute ${U,D,R,L}$ and word in those letters must have the same probability as the "permuted" word..

I would simply say that since the square is symmetric across its diagonals and the step directions are all equally likely, the probabilities of "vertical side first" and "horizontal side first" must be equal to each other when starting on a diagonal so from $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,3)$ and also from $(1,3)$, $(3,1)$
